# Split words without function in c

Tags: c, function

I have created a snapshot void function. The user gives a registration number like "M/12/222" where 12 is a batch number, 222  is an 'e number'. I created code like this but it does not work properly. It does not split the above number and batch number from the registration number

Here we don't use any other external libraries.

```
char enumber[9];
char batchNo[2];
char eNO[3];
printf("Enter the Registration Number: ");
scanf("%s",enumber);
printf("%s\n",enumber);
for (int i=2;i<8;i++){
    if(2<=i&&i<4){
        batchNo[i-2]=enumber[i];
        printf("%c\n",batchNo[i-2]);
    }
    if(i>4){
        eNO[i-5]=enumber[i];
    }

}
printf("%s\n",batchNo);
```

Comment: If "/" is always present between values then use that to determine where each bock of data is.

Comment: for starters, `printf("c\n",batchNo[i-2]);` --> `printf("%c\n",batchNo[i-2]);` (added the `%` in front of `c`). That gives the correct output for `batchNo`. And when I print out `eNO`, looks like it's characters are getting set correctly as well. Make sure to add `NUL` terminators if you want them to be strings.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use what's available https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm

Comment: Note that you need more space in the `batchNo` and `eNO` arrays to allow for a null terminator so that the results are strings, not just character arrays.  You are very trusting that your user will never type anything wrong — and users (even you) are generally very unreliable and will find ways to type "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" when you thought they'd only type "hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

```
printf("c\n",batchNo[i-2]);
```

to

```
printf("%c",batchNo[i-2]);
```

Then your output will be:

`12`

The issues that I see are that you're not using the correct format type for the data that you're passing to the `printf` statement.

If you wish to output your values outside of ther loop then you should treat them as strings, remembering that a c string is a null terminated character array and that variables should be initialised before use.

If your code is changed to allow for this then it should work. Here's my test program:

```
int main()
{
    char enumber[9] = "M/12/222";
    char batchNo[3] = {0};
    char eNO[4] = {0};

    for (int i=2;i<8;i++){
        if(2<=i&&i<4){
            batchNo[i-2]=enumber[i];
        }
        if(i>4){
            eNO[i-5]=enumber[i];
        }
    }
    printf("batchNo = %s\n",batchNo);
    printf("eNO = %s\n",eNO);   
}
```

Your get:

```
batchNo = 12
eNO = 222
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to put '\0' terminators at the end of strings**. Without those, printf will loop forever and print the whole world until it gets a random zero somewhere.

So:

```
char batchNo[3]; // one for the zero
char eNO[4]; // one for the zero
```

And

```
batchNo[2]='\0';
eNO[3]='\0';
```

anywhere.

**Additional warning**: scanf will let you write more than 9 chars, if you wish, letting you write values in random memory. Good for demo testing, don't use like this anywhere a real user is involved.

Comment: See the C example here!
https://toggl.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/toggl-how-to-save-the-princess-in-8-programming-languages-0c32e93f47f3f6401913846c4c184e3e.jpg